# Get text of dropdownlist in jquery

Tags: jquery, text, drop-down-menu

I make 4 dropdownlist in html at run time and they have the same id.now i want to  get selected text for all dropdownlists in jquery?

Comment: Try `var selectedValues = [];
$('select').each(function() {
    selectedValues.push($(this).val());
});`

Comment: i wrote this code but it does not work $(function () {
                   $("#btn1").click(function () {
                       var selectedValues = [];
                       $('#se1').each(function () {
                           selectedValues.push($(this).val());
                           $.each(selectedValues, function (idx, value) {
                               alert(value);
                           })
                          
                       })
                      
                      
                   })
               })

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned, IDs must be UNIQUE. Use class instead, here i make illustration how to do that :

**HTML**

```
<!-- see all element having class definition instead of ID -->
<select class="mySelect">
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="a1">a1</option>
</select>
<select class="mySelect">
  <option value="b">b</option>
  <option value="b1">b1</option>
</select>
<select class="mySelect">
  <option value="c">c</option>
  <option value="c1">c1</option>
</select>
<select class="mySelect">
  <option value="d">d</option>
  <option value="d1">d1</option>
</select>
<button>Get Text</button>
```

**JS**

```
// if you're creating element on the fly
// it is better to delegate by using .on
$(document).on('click', 'button', function () {
  var text;
  // we use .map here to mapping value into array form
  text = $('.mySelect').map(function () {
    return $('option:selected', this).text();
  }).get();
  console.log(text.join());
});
// you can use .each also like Tushar's answer on comment section
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/jvtdvtxe/)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH

Comment: You're welcome mate, consider accepting this answer if helpful will make others can refer to it later on by clicking on "right icon" at left side of this answer.

Comment: I use this code $(function () { $("#sel1").change(function () { var qa = $(this).val(); var s = $("#txt2").val() * qa; $("#span1").html(""); $("#span1").append('<label>'+s+'</label>'); }) }); and it works fine but when i link another jquery file in my mvc pro it does not work